# ASyncTask load GridView thumbnails loads latest file twice, then slowly loads from the top of the list

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask

I'm using an ASyncTask to load my thumbnails in a GridView layout that I have, but when I refresh the data, the thumbnails load in an odd order. It always loads the last element first, but it renders it with the first elements thumbnail, then re-renders it with the proper thumbnail (the last elements), then it properly loads every other thumbnail from first to second-last. It also reloads the images many times and is fairly slow at loading them (16mp images however)

Here's my GridView adapter (with the ASyncTask).

```
public class ReceiptListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    public ReceiptListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Receipt> receipts){
        super(context, 0, receipts);
//        getItem(1);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder holder;

        // Lookup view for data population
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.receipt_list_element, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TitleView);
            holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.DateView);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.containerImage);
            holder.spn = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Receipt receipt = (Receipt) getItem(position);
        holder.imagePath = receipt.getFilepath();
        final int tWidth = receipt.getWidth();

        // manipulate data here...
        holder.spn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.title.setText(receipt.getDesc());

        new AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, Bitmap>() {

            private ViewHolder h;

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(ViewHolder... t) {
                h = t[0];
                Bitmap thumb = ExifUtil.rotateBitmap(h.imagePath, ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(
                        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(h.imagePath),
                        tWidth,
                        tWidth));
                return thumb;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                    h.spn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    h.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    h.image.setImageBitmap(result);

            }
        }.execute(holder);




        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }




    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView title;
        private TextView date;
        private ImageView image;
        private String imagePath;
        private ProgressBar spn;
    }

}
```

Comment: actually its a problem of AsyncTask, you are using to download image, you should try Either Glide or Picasso library for it.

Comment: the problem with it loading all the images in a weird order, or it being slow? and i'll check out picasso, thanks.

Comment: yeah, its not maintaining any cache implementation for already downloaded image so every image is downloading every time and this makes slow to load in imageView that's why image are overlapping each other till all image not downloaded....i will update a solution for it in few minutes..don't worry..:)

Comment: i have posted my answer please update your Code.

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: i ended up going with picasso, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id go with just using another library, but let me explain where some of the issues are coming. First as per [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.htm)

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

Which meanst that you are loading only 1 thumbnail at a time. Your second issue is because viewHolder is actually reused. You create 2 AsyncTasks for the same view, which are executed in different times (but correct order). This can be fixed by keeping refference to the Task, and stopping it before creating new one.

Comment: @343N, use glide instead of picasso. it is more enhanced and efficient than picasso.

Answer (score 1):

> I have Replace your AsyncTask with Glide Library Update Your Code with
>   below

```
public class ReceiptListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

        public ReceiptListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Receipt> receipts){
            super(context, 0, receipts);
//        getItem(1);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Get the data item for this position
            // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            ViewHolder holder;

            // Lookup view for data population
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.receipt_list_element, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
                holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TitleView);
                holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.DateView);
                holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.containerImage);
                holder.spn = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            Receipt receipt = (Receipt) getItem(position);
            holder.imagePath = receipt.getFilepath();
            final int tWidth = receipt.getWidth();

            // manipulate data here...
            holder.spn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.title.setText(receipt.getDesc());

            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(holder.imagePath)
                    .into(holder.image);

            /*new AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, Bitmap>() {

                private ViewHolder h;

                @Override
                protected Bitmap doInBackground(ViewHolder... t) {
                    h = t[0];
                    Bitmap thumb = ExifUtil.rotateBitmap(h.imagePath, ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(
                            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(h.imagePath),
                            tWidth,
                            tWidth));
                    return thumb;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);

                    h.spn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    h.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    h.image.setImageBitmap(result);

                }
            }.execute(holder);*/




            // Return the completed view to render on screen
            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            private TextView title;
            private TextView date;
            private ImageView image;
            private String imagePath;
            private ProgressBar spn;
        }

    }
```

> Open you `build.gradle` and add this dependency

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
```

Comment: I used Picasso but since they're extremely similar, your answer is basically correct, but I'm giving the correct answer to someone else due to their explanation

Comment: Picasso and Glide are much similar..you can continue with any one....thanks for your Appreciation...:)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly solving this issue, I would propose two things:
1. Use RecyclerView and RecyclerView.Adapter instead of what you have now. 2. Use an image loading library like Picasso or Glide instead of loading it in an AsyncTask. You have many things to consider when loading things asynchronously yourself, and a library already takes care of many possible errors.

See how to implement a ViewHolder pattern with RecyclerView here: https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

Comment: Picasso is very easy to use, and the link explains RecyclerView in detail. Good luck!

Comment: Ended up just going with Picasso, I may look into RecyclerView later if it's of need. Thank you.

Comment: It is not a must in any sense, but rather a cleaner and more widespread solution. But Good luck!